# Why $p$ disappears in this equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to understand why $p$ disappears in this proof from this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471625469):

Knowing the $r_i$ are the residues that exceed $p/2$ and $s_j$ the remaining residues:

[image]
[image]

I really need help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd number is congruent to $1$ modulo $2$.

Comment: ok, so? I didn't understand why this solve my problem

Comment: $p$ turned into $1$ modulo $2$. Your equation, where you say $p$ is "missing", is modulo $2$.

Comment: I have a meta question, I didn't understand where the author uses this hypothesis $(a,2p)=1$, should I write another question or simply edit it?

Comment: @user42912 Please make another question.